# Count sets of pairwise non-containing sets

Tags: combinatorics

For a finite set $S$ of cardinality $N$, define the sets of pairwise non-containing sets as $\{T\in P(P(S)): \nexists X,Y \in T \ X\subset Y\}$. That is, the sets of subsets of $S $ containing no members that are proper subsets of one another. Is there a better name for pairwise non-containing sets, or a known formula for counting the sets thereof, given $N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are referring to an anti-chain: a collection of sets $S$ so that no two sets contained in the collection are comparable, i.e. no $A, B\in S$ with $A\neq B$ and $A\subset B$.

The opposite of an anti-chain is a chain, a set $S$ of sets for which every pair of sets $A,B\in S$ either satisfy $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @TravisJ's answer, one strategy would be to find *maximal* antichains - subsets of non-comparable subsets of $[n] = \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$, to which you can add no more subsets of $[n]$ and still have an antichain.

Unfortunately, the number of antichains of $2^{[n]}$ is counted by [Dedekind numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_number), for which no nice formula is known (you can see the summation formula yourself, it's quite nasty!).